# Power Automate reminders to be send on number of days from initial day

Tags: arrays, integer, power-automate

I am working on SharePoint List solution that acts on date trigger.
The base date is a date of parcel receipt.
I need a set of reminders that stop once Picked field is turned "yes".

Idea here is:

- Initial info on "New Item" - **done and work fine**
- Flow to send reminders on 2nd, 4th and 7th working day from the initial date (parcel receipt).
- Fields Reminder 1, 2 and 3 to be updated by the flow accordingly

I can not create a flow that will meet above criteria and execute on each record respectively. I have constructed various flows, but each of those seem create a different issue.

Solution I believe will solve that would need to be constructed with following elements:

1. Schedule run every 1 week on workdays (Mo-Fri) as Initial trigger
2. Get items filtered ODATA Picked eq No
3. Condition on Arrival if greater or equal Today -X (X a number of days for reminder)
4. Send reminder email to Parcel Recipient

My biggest concern is step 3 as I am lacking syntax/formula function writing skills. Can you suggest a steps to follow?

Comment: Well "Get Item" just returns one item. "Apply to each" expects an array of items in order to loop through each one. Since you only have one item you can get rid of the "Apply to each" entirely.

Comment: Or if you are expecting to loop through multiple items from that list then you should be using the "Get items" action instead, which will return multiple items.

Comment: @SarahCox has nailed it.  My question is, why is it in an `Apply to each` in the first place?  Did you use `Get items` first and then change it to `Get item`?  Either way, you need to take it out.